# Configure kile and biblatex

Tags: biblatex, kile

How do people configure kile to work with biblatex? I have two bibliographies

```
\begin{refsection}
...
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
...
\end{refsection}
```

and to get this to compile I need to run at least

```
pdflatex file

bibtex file1-blx

bibtex file2-blx

pdflatex file
```

Can this be made automatic in kile?

(I am on ubuntu.)

EDIT: Herbert gives a method using biber which works. However it is a pain to get the latest biber and biblatex in ubuntu as I mention in the comments. However, his method also suggests that a similar custom build option for kile could be made to work for biblatex+bibtex too which would enable you to keep the ubuntu version of texlive.

Comment: Consider to switch from BibTeX to biber -- with biber, subdivided bibliographies should be processed in a single pass.

Comment: Is it obvious how to do that in kile? The normal pdflatex build option in kile just runs "pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %source" and there is a tick box on the same page for "Automatically run additional tools" but I don't know how to configure what that does.

Comment: Sorry -- I don't use kile. Maybe [this](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/build.html#id329006) link is helpful.

Comment: New Kile and new texlive/biblatex both uses logreq. Kile will recompile as necessary automatically. No extra tools necessary.

Comment: @Raphael The **installation of the latest TeX Live version** is not too complicated. Please follow this [short tutorial](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120710/how-to-manually-install-tex-live-2012/) and you certainly will be successful as I have been.

Comment: The standard question for this kind of stuff is now [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). There is also a Kile answer over there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Go to `Settings->Configure Kile`
- Choose on the left `Build`
- Choose `New` and insert the name `biber`
- Now
  click on this new item and insert on
  the right into the field for the
  command
  `/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-linux/biber`
  (this example shows my path)
- Into the
  parameter field insert `"%S"`
- Now
  enable the `Quick Build` item on the
  left and add `biber` in the field on
  the right.

Close the windows and everything should work. At the first time when running biber it takes a lot of time because it has to unpack all included files into a temporary directory. In your document do not forget to set

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,...]{biblatex}
```

With the latest version of `biblatex` it should be the default.

Comment: If I have to move to biber, how do you use it from the command line?  I set \usepackage[backend=biber, arxiv=pdf, firstinits=true]{biblatex} but pdflatex file gives me Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file(s):
(biblatex)                file2-blx.aux . But biber file2-blx gives me an error FATAL - Cannot find control file 'file2-blx.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

Comment: I also tried biber file but get WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 0.8i, expected version 1.4
FATAL - No data files on command line or provided in the file 'file.bcf'! Exiting

Comment: First delete old auxiliary files. It is safe to delete _all_ files except the `.tex` one. Then run `pdflatex file`, then run `biber file` and again twice `pdflatex`, that is all.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Here is a sample output with a sample latex file.  http://pastebin.com/yTynVz4i  . I also tested it using pdflatex and bibtex and it worked fine.

Comment: your  biblatex is completely out of date! It should be of version 1.4 but you had 0.8i. Update it

Comment: Being on ubuntu I have now removed all installed texlive packages, installed texlive from the official website, removed kile ubuntu packages, compiled kile from source and installed.  biber now works :) Kile also appears to but I notice Quickbuild is making a ps and then converting it to pdf. I would prefer it to use pdflatex if possible.

Comment: Go again into the configuration and edited the Quick Build in the right window. Remove "latex ->dvips ->ps2pdf" and replace it by "pdflatex-> biber->..."

Comment: Thanks. Got it to work in the end. The secret seems to be to use '%S' with a capital S for the biber tool config.

Comment: The default BibTeX tool has the further settings "source extension: aux" and "target extension: bbl". Is it a good idea to copy these settings to the new biber tool, too?

Comment: Secondly, the default kile tool chain does some magic to call bibtex when needed but not otherwise. As far as I understand it, this happens when a tool is marked as having the class "LaTeX" (as has my custom LuaLaTeX tool for example). I do not understand how to make this magic invoke biber instead of bibtex though.

Comment: I found a slightly better but not good way: you can make biber one "configuration" for the BibTeX command. This should make kile treat biber like the regular bibtex. Unfortunately it doesn't work. My guess is that kile doesn't recognize the "Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file" line because it doesn't say "please (re)run bibtex on the file".

Comment: @Christian: Please make this an answer! Even thought it does not work in some cases, it's very useful and since kile has an integrated terminal, you can force regeneration by running `rm texfile.bbl` easily.

Comment: @Christian: "source extension: aux" should become "source extension: bcf" (see biblatex.pdf 3.11)

Comment: @frafl This works although using the `bcf` files triggers `biber` and a second `pdflatex` run every time. Since this more than doubles the compile time if neither bibliography nor references were changed, a different solution would be better. I'll summarize this discussion into an answer after some more experimentation.

Comment: Can you please update your post with *detailed* bullet points what and how to do it, so I can get a PDF file with just one click?

Comment: After, quite literally six hours of trying to figure out, I got slightly improved answer. Instead of `'%S'` you are supposed to type `"%S"`. Then, in the QuickBuild add PdfLatex, biber and PDFLatex again. This generates a correct pdf file, with only an error about `defernumbers`, which can be fixed by adding `\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers]{biblatex}`

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: It seems like my method calls biber every time it compiles after all, so scratch this. I was pretty certain I checked that it worked like I wanted, but it seems like I was wrong. I'll leave my answer below anyway.

> Since this is the top result in Google for "kile biber" and "kile
>   biblatex", and the question doesn't have a perfect solution
>   (*[@Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20336/31078)'s answer
>   seems to run biber every time I compile, which is unnecessary*), I'll
>   try and explain my solution to this problem. I'm not completely
>   certain I understand how my solution works, but at least it seems to
>   do what I want, which is:
>
> - Automatically run `biber` and rerun `pdflatex` when needed (when I change my bibliography or citations) when I run the tool `PDFLaTeX` in
>     Kile
>
> To make Kile work as wanted this is what I did:
>
> First we make a new configuration for the `BibTeX` tool:
>
> - Go to `Settings -> Configure Kile... -> Tools -> Build`
> - Select `BibTeX` in the window under `Select a tool`
> - On the right side under `Choose a configuration for the tool BibTeX`, press the `New` button
> - Enter the name `Biber`
> - In the `General` tab:
>
>   - in the `Commmand` field enter `biber`, in the `Options` field enter `"%S"`
> - In the `Advanced` tab
>
>   - Set everything equal to the `Default` configuration, except the `Source extension`, which should be `bcf`
> - Set everything equal to the `Default` configuration in the `Menu` tab
>
> Now just make sure that this new configuration is selected in the drop
>   down box `Choose a configuration for the tool BibTeX`, and that the
>   box `Automatically run additional tools` is ticked off in the
>   configuration you use for the `PDFLaTeX` tool. Now the tool `PDFLaTeX`
>   can be run by itself, or used in another tool like `QuickBuild`, and
>   it will automatically run `biber` and rerun `pdflatex` when needed.
>
> I'm on Linux Mint 15 (olivia) (basically Ubuntu 13.04), using Kile
>   version `2.1.3`, pdflatex version `3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live
>   2012/Debian)`, and biber version `0.9.9`. I think those are the
>   versions from the default repositories, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings, Configure Kile. In the left panel, select Tools and Build. Press the "New..." button. Follow the next image instructions:

[image: Biber and build settings]

Now, from "Select a tool" listbox, select QuickBuild. Perform the necessary changes to have the same that the illustration:

[image: Quickbuild settings]

Press OK and compile your file/project :)

**Reference**: [Florian Schöngaßner](http://florian.schoengassner.at/ubuntu-12-04-kile-texlive-biblatex-biber.html) webpage.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use `latexmk` with Kile, i.e. in the Build menu add the new tools:

1) compile class:

```
name: LaTeXMk
command: latexmk
options: -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode" -pdf '%source'
target extension: pdf
```

2) quickbuild class:

```
name: QuickBuild with LaTeXMk
tools: choose LaTeXMk first and then ForwarPDF
add to build menu: Quick
```

Then you can add QuickBuild with LaTeXMk to a toolbar and use it as a default tool - it should automatically detect engines it needs to run.

For me it works flawlessly with biber/Biblatex and SyncTeX works as well.

Of course you need to install `latexmk`, in Fedora with

```
sudo dnf install latexmk
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple python script (which you can find [here](https://gist.github.com/ihincks/9e5bb2ec0dd49a2c574b)) that calls `bibtex` for every `.aux` corresponding to some latex file. 
I have special reasons for not being able to use `biber`.
So for your example,

```
multi-bibtex [options] file
```

is equivalent to

```
bibtex [options] file1-blx
bibtex [options] file2-blx
```

Now in Kile (which I don't use) you should be able to change instances of `bibtex` to `multi-bibtex`, and of course, get `biblatex` to use the `bibtex` backend.

To install on ubuntu,

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/9e5bb2ec0dd49a2c574b.git /tmp/mbibtex
chmod a+x /tmp/mbibtex/multi-bibtex
sudo mv /tmp/mbibtex/multi-bibtex /usr/local/bin/
```

Which downloads the python script and puts it in `/sur/local/bin`. Usual disclaimer about how you should be careful about downloading scripts and using them yadda yadda.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Lukasz

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~latexmk into windows~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**WSL + Kile-Windows** (Windows Subsystem Linux) latexmk installed in Ubuntu or Kalilinux etc. and Kile installed in Windows, Kile command:

```
c:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-lxss-bash_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_251beae725bc7de5\bash.exe -c "latexmk -pdf -pvc %S.tex"
```

Also works with TEXStudio

Into the run command .latexmkrc put:

```
$pdf_previewer = 'start /mnt/c/Progra~1/SumatraPDF/SUMATRAPDF.EXE';
```

I use sumatrapdf pdf viewer in windows.

This works as **Real-Time-LaTeX** , vanilla TeX Live and compile LaTeX code in real-time. Have fun ;)

Comment: path to bash.exe in windows change dependent of your Windows10 Version 
'c:\windows\ dir /s bash.exe'