# Configure kile to include biber

Tags: biblatex, biber, kile

I am trying to add biber to QuickBuild in Kile and I tried following the instructions in [Configure kile and biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20328/) post. However, seems like the instructions are for a different version of Kile. Could someone help me understand what to include for in the blank spaces of the screenshots I've attached. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are trying to follow instructions in another post, please provide a link. For one thing, somebody may then check to see if an answer there needs clarification, update or expansion.

Comment: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/106162) is another reference for this which includes [a Kile-specific answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154763/106162)

Answer (score 1):

Under **Build**, I have

- command: `biber`
- options: `'%S'`

Under **Advanced**, I have

- type: `Run outside Kile`
- class: `Compile`
- source extension: `bcf`
- target extension: `bbl`
- target file:
- relative dir:
- state: `Editor`

I don't know how many of these **Advanced** settings matter, but this is what I'm using.

Note that `biber` is in my default `PATH` so I do not need to specify the full path to the binary. I recommend ensuring that your TeX binaries are in your `PATH` even if you prefer to specify full paths in Kile.